# Insert Error in 'Aura Components Basics - Connect to Salesforce with Server-Side Controllers

Tags: apex, query, aura

I just completed the Aura Components Basics - Connect to Salesforce with Server-Side Controllers.
Wrote the code and passed the text. But upon testing it in the App Preview, I get insert errors. The nature of this insert error is unclear.
The apex code:

```
public with sharing class CampingListController {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Camping_Item__c> getItems() {
        return [SELECT id,name,price__c,Quantity__c,Packed__c
               FROM Camping_Item__c];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Camping_Item__c saveItem (Camping_Item__c item) {
        upsert item;
        return item;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding error:

```
14:33:41:004 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, un12331__Camping_Item__c: bad field names on insert/update call: Price__c, Packed__c, Quantity__c: [Price__c, Packed__c, Quantity__c]
```

I have the Camping_Item defined in the Object Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your org has a namespace (`un12331`), so you need to include the namespace for each field: `un12331__Packed__c`,`un12331__Price__c`,`un12331__Quantity__c`. Standard fields don't need the namespace, such as Name or OwnerId. It's probably a better idea to create a new Playground that doesn't have a namespace for trailheads that don't call for one, and reserve your namespaced org for trailheads that do.